# counting different chars without converting to lower case

Tags: java, arrays, char

The method:

```
public static int noOfLetters (String str)
```

I'm given a string and need to return the number of unique letters in the string, capital and small letters considered equal but you can't convert them using lowercase vice versa. I tried many things. This is the best I could code:
for example:"cd$aD " would return 3

```
public static int noOfLetters(String str) {
    char[] alphabet = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
    int count = 0;
    int j = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++) {
        if(str.charAt(i) != alphabet[j])
            j++;
        count++;
    }
    return count;
```

Comment: Does the string only contain a-z and A-Z?

Comment: Is use of `Character.isUpperCase` allowed? You can simply find index of it in alphabet array by doing `ch - 'A'`  by checking if it's uppercase

Comment: no the string can contain things like $ and it won`t count sorry i didn`t mention

Comment: Hello, shouldn't `cd$aD` return 4 instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be able to do it by adding a condition in your loop for all characters which lie between `'A'` and `'Z'` which you can convert to lowercase by subtracting it from `'A'`:

```java
public static int noOfLetters(String str) {
    Set<Character> distinctChars = new HashSet<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        boolean isUpperCaseChar = str.charAt(i) >= 'A' && str.charAt(i) <= 'Z';
        boolean isLowerCaseChar = str.charAt(i) >= 'a' && str.charAt(i) <= 'z';
        if (isUpperCaseChar || isLowerCaseChar) {
            char convertedLowerCaseChar = str.charAt(i);
            if (isUpperCaseChar) {
                convertedLowerCaseChar = (char) (str.charAt(i) - 'A' + 'a');
            }
            distinctChars.add(convertedLowerCaseChar);
        }
    }

    return distinctChars.size();
}
```

I tested it using this code :

```
System.out.println(noOfLetters("rohankumar"));
System.out.println(noOfLetters("rohankumarROHAN"));
System.out.println(noOfLetters("rohankumarROHAN-$"));
System.out.println(noOfLetters("cd$aD"));
```

It prints the following:

```
8
8
8
3
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to enumerate the chars and put them inside a case insensitive map.

At the end of the loop you should get the keys collection size to get the amount of unique letters.

Here https://www.baeldung.com/java-map-with-case-insensitive-keys is a tutorial on how to use a case insensitive map. .

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with

```
str.chars().filter(ch -> (ch >= 65 && ch <= 90) || (ch >= 97 && ch <= 122)).map(ch -> ch >= 97? ch-32 : ch).distinct().count();
```

You are first filtering out all characters different from letters and then converting all to uppercase but you are not using toLowercase or toUppercase methods if this is the ones that are not allowed

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Set<Character>` which you will add each alphabet char you have seen:

To understand the trick, you can visit: [ASCII Table](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Epattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html)

```
public static int noOfLetters(String str) {
    List<Character> alphabet = Arrays.asList('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z');
    Set<Character> uniqueAlphabetSeen = new HashSet<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char c = str.charAt(i);

        if (alphabet.contains(c)){
            uniqueAlphabetSeen.add(c);
        }
        else if(c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z'){
            uniqueAlphabetSeen.add((char) (c -'A' + 'a'));
        }
    }

    return uniqueAlphabetSeen.size();
}
```

Input:

```
System.out.println(noOfLetters("cd$aD"));
```

Output:

```
3
```